# <p:ajax> for <h:selectBooleanCheckBox> not working

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to call a method on the bean when the checkbox is selected/de-selected. When I select/deselect the checkbox inside the header it works fine and calls the method. But the second checkbox doesn't seem to work.
Below is my code (Note that this code is inside `h:dataTable`).
I am using 
**xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"**

```
    <h:column rendered="#{tableID.equals('approved-payments-table')}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox_select_all" value="false">
            <p:ajax id="process_select_all" 
                     process="checkbox_select_all"
                     actionListener="#{batchCreationHandler.selectAllCheckBoxListener()}"
                     event="click"/>
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </f:facet>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox_ABCDEFG" value="#{false}">
            <p:ajax id="processItemInvoice" process="checkbox_ABCDEFG" 
                    partialSubmit="true" 
                    listener="#{batchCreationHandler.selectAllCheckBoxListener()}" 
                    event="click"/>
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            &#160;
        </f:facet>
    </h:column>
```

Comment: Are you actually using PrimeFaces 2.x?

Comment: Did you try identical variants?  `partialSubmit="true"` in the first box and `actionListener=...` in the 2nd one?

Comment: @Holger, 
Yes, I tried multiple variations but none seems to be working.

Comment: @Kukeltje, 
This is a legacy project and hence we are using PF.

Comment: @Dotcomwizard with the 2nd box you get an error ` javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException` because your value expression is illegal.
This tells me, you didn't try identical versions...

Comment: @Holger Can you elaborate on your statement. If I do not use value="#{false}", it doesn't work in the 2nd checkbox.

Comment: `value` normally needs a getter and a setter. I don't know, why `value="false"` doesn't throw an error, but `value="#{false}"` throws javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException in my  test (because the setter is missed)